# Confusion over .map transform closure

Tags: swift

The code below compiles and runs OK, and seems to indicate that the `closure` and `String.init(describing:)` functions are completely equivalent in their signature, since `.map` method happily takes both of them.

```swift
let someDict: [String: String] = [
    "string1" : "Hello",
    "string2" : "Bye",
]

//One way to call .map
var closure = { (key: String, value: String) -> String in
    return "The key is \(key), the value is \(value)"
}
someDict.map(closure)

//Another way to call .map
someDict.map(String.init(describing:))
```

But how is it possible to place into `.map` a `String.init(describing:)` function which is a function of only 1 argument, while `.map` expects a function of 2 arguments? Or am i misunderstanding something here..

Btw, checking the documentation shows that it really does expect a function of 2 arguments:

```
transform: ((key: String, value: String)) throws -> T
```

Comment: When accessed by `map`, a dictionary is a sequence of tuple pairs.  You can access the tuple as a whole, which is what happens when you `map` it with `String.init(describing:))`.  The `tuple` is converted to a String.  Or you can access the components of the tuple as you did in your first call to `map`.  Both are valid.

Comment: Well, I did realize earlier, that apparently the `String.init(describing:)` have something to do with whole SINGLE tuple passing - otherwise it's an impossible situation. However, i wasn't able to find the overloaded `.map` method definition in the spec.  All I see is that `.map` takes a function of TWO arguments. Would you mind pointing me to this overloaded definition then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Btw, checking the documentation shows that it really does expect a
>   function of 2 arguments:
>
> ```
> transform: ((key: String, value: String)) throws -> T
> ```

Actually, no.  Notice the extra parentheses `()`. It shows that it expects a function that takes one argument which is a tuple containing two elements.

Consider this example:

```
// function foo takes two arguments
func foo(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

// function bar takes one tuple with two elements
func bar(_ a: (Int, Int)) -> Int {
    return a.0 + a.1
}

let f1 = foo
print(type(of: f1))  // (Int, Int) -> Int

let f2 = bar
print(type(of: f2))  // ((Int, Int)) -> Int
```

So, the extra parentheses tell us that `map` is expecting one argument that is a tuple containing two elements.

The closure passed to `map` always operates on a single element from the sequence at a time.  That element **can be a tuple** such as your case, and then your closure can *deconstruct* that tuple into multiple values.

Consider this example:

```
// tup is a tuple containing 3 values
let tup = (1, true, "hello")

// deconstruct the tuple through assignment
let (x, y, z) = tup

print(x)  // 1
print(y)  // true
print(z)  // hello
```

So in this example:

```
var closure = { (key: String, value: String) -> String in
    return "The key is \(key), the value is \(value)"
}
someDict.map(closure)
```

`map`'s closure is given a tuple of the form `(key: String, value: String)` and the closure is deconstructing that into `key` and `value` just as the `let` did above.

In this example:

```
someDict.map(String.init(describing:))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
someDict.map({ String(describing: $0) })
```

`map` is taking the whole tuple and passing it to `String(describing:)`.

Comment: Just a minute before i read this excellent explanation, i started thinking in the above direction and even constructed an example similar to above. Thanks again.